# How to update a PHP variable with AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, json

I have an AJAX script that used to replace an entire div with new html including the `<input>` markup:

```
<script>
function show_locations(str) {

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        }

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        var a = xmlhttp.responseText;
            a = JSON.parse(a);
            document.getElementById('locations_dropdown').innerHTML=a.location;
            document.getElementById('dm').innerHTML=a.dm;
            document.getElementById('dm_email').innerHTML=a.dm_email;
    }
}

xmlhttp.open('GET','includes/get_locations.php?d='+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();

}
</script>
```

The `document.getElementById('dm_email').innerHTML=a.dm_email;').innerHTML=a.dm_email;` would replace the `<div id=dm_email></div>` contents with a new `<input>` markup which would include the new email value in `value=""` here:

```
<div id="dm_email">
    <input type="email" value="">
</div>
```

But, now I know that sending html markup through json is a bad practice, so how can I change my AJAX script above to replace just the value of the input?

I tried this:

```
document.getElementById('dm_email').value=a.dm_email;
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, many relatively big websites take pure HTML code through AJAX. Receiving different pieces in JSON, I don't see why it would be any bad. However, if you want to avoid it you can send the "php variables" (as you call them) alone and create the HTML in the AJAX callback.

Comment: I called them php variables because they used to be variables. Then I changed the code and didn't update my question. I really just want to select the value of the input and insert the email.

Comment: `document.getElementById('dm_email').value` will get the div and not the input in the div. For that you will need to do something like `document.getElementById('dm_email').children[0].value` (play around with that... don't hold me to that). Or you could try adding an id to the input if you have control over that.

Comment: Or give your input-tag an ID, so you don't need to parse the children ;)

Comment: Yes, I just realized that now. Thanks, Sebastian!